# Possibilities to quit a function

Tags: c++, c, function, exception, return

I was wondering about a general topic in C/C++.
Let's say we're executing a function A() which calls a function B(), can we be sure that the call of B() in A() will always return "after" the call itself.

In a more general question, which are the possibilities to quit a function ?

The C keywords are (Wikipedia) : auto, break, case, char, const (C89), continue, default, do, double, else, enum (C89), extern, float, for, goto, if, inline (C99), int, long, register, restrict (C99), return, short, signed (C89), sizeof, static, struct, switch, typedef, union, unsigned, void (C89), volatile (C89), while, _Bool (C99), _Complex (C99), _Imaginary (C99).

As far as I know, the one interesting in this topic are :

- **break/continue** : Used in loops or switchs (as I was told by GCC after trying), they can't exit a function.
- **goto** : The scope of labels is restricted by the functions so a goto can't exit a function
- **return** : Can exit a function but always returns to the instruction after the call. We're safe with this one.
- The **exit()/abort()** functions which will end up the application. We won't return to the calling point, but .. we won't return at all.

I think that is for the C language. Do you think there is another way to quit a function and without returning to the calling point ?

---

In C++, exceptions will obviously not return to the calling point. They will either go to a catch block or reach the calling function, looking for a catch block.

As far as I known, it would be the only case.

Thanks for helping me =)

Comment: Do you only care about standard C?  Or are [`setjmp(3)`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?setjmp+3) and [`longjmp(3)`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?longjmp+3) interesting to you?

Comment: `-1` there's no such language as C/C++

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz:  That seems like such a quibble, given their shared heritage, and the fact that many of the older C constructs work in C++.

Comment: It sounds like your real question may be focused on "reachability" and/or statically analyzing/proving statements about code.  Are you writing such an analysis tool?

Comment: @CarlNorum: `setjmp` and `longjmp` are standard C. They're also standard C++, but more-or-less unusable in that language.

Comment: I am effectively writing a statical analyser on CFGs. The objective of this question is to avoid inlining the CFGs of the application to one big and proceed modularly. If a function always returns to its calling point. I might be able to consider it as the basic block cointaining the call.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, thanks - I thought it was just in POSIX.

Comment: @JoeZ the fact these statements work doesn't mean they should be ever used.

Answer (score 1):

In standard C (using `setjmp/longjmp`) and C++ (using exceptions), it is possible to effectively return to marked points closer to the root of the CFG. In effect, a function may never return, but if it does return, it will be to the point following the call.

However, the low-level nature of the `setjmp` mechanism actually makes it possible to implement coroutines (albeit in a non-portable way). Posix attempted to improve on this situation by mandating `makecontext` and friends, which allow for explicit stack swapping, but those functions were deprecated in Posix.1-2001 and removed from Posix.1-2008, citing portability issues, with the suggestion that threads be used instead. Nonetheless, there are a number of coroutine libraries in use which use these features to allow C programmers to enjoy the flexibility of coroutines.

In coroutine control flow, while the execution path following a (co)call might be sinuous, it is still the case that a function call either never returns or eventually returns to the immediately following point. However, the low-level nature of the C library facilities makes it possible to implement more complex control flows, in which a given (co)call might, for example, return several times. (I've never seen this particular anomaly implemented in production code, but I can't claim to have seen even a tiny percentage of all production code in the world :) ).

A gcc extension to C allows for the use of "label values", which are pointers to labels in the code. These are real values (of type `void *`) so they can be passed as arguments to functions. (The gcc manual warns against doing this.) With some reverse-engineering, it would probably be possible to write a function which takes one or more label arguments and uses one of them as a return point. That would clearly be a misuse of the feature, would likely not be either portable nor future-proof, and would almost certainly break any coding standards in existence.

The interesting thing about the C library facilities, as opposed to C++ exceptions which are actually part of the core language, is that they really are functions; in C, as with many programming languages, functions can be called indirectly through function pointers so that it might not be readily computable through static analysis which function is being called at a given call site. So, at least in theory, I'd say all bets are off. But in practice it's probably a safe assumption that a function call will either eventually return to the immediately following point or return to somewhere down the call stack, possibly the operating system environment.

Answer (score 0):

Look up `setjmp()` and `longjmp()`.  `setjmp()` records a certain amount of local state at the point it's called.  `longjmp()` will return, potentially across several levels of function, to the point where you called `setjmp()`.

You can use it for a primitive form of exception handling in C.  It's very, very rarely used.

Answer (score 0):

You can exit a function with

- return
- silently at the end of its body (without explicit return in a `void function()`)
- an exception
- a `longjmp()`
- inline assembly jumping to some address

Comment: Undefined behavior.  Since it can do anything, it can make you leave a function.  (Most importantly, here, undefined behavior can modify the return address on the stack.)

Comment: So basically, it can happen only using longjump() or setjump() or with an inline assembly jump in C, and with an exception in C++ ?

Comment: it can happen in all five cases I described above, plus the one James described, although I haven't seen the latter happening in reality. Put it is still a valid possibility, it is just not very likely.

Comment: Well, James gives an excellent example:  stack smashing.  That's a widely used attack vector for escalating privileges.  It relies on the undefined behavior that results when you go beyond an array's normal bounds, and uses it to take over a task.  You could also argue that crashing is another form of "undefined behavior causing you not to return as expected from a function."

Answer (score 0):

I remember creating this func when i needed a way to quit a big program without exit

```
int     my_exit()
{
  pid_t pid;
  int   i;

  pid = getpid();
  i = kill(pid, SIGQUIT);
  if (i == -1)
    return (-1);
  return (0);
}
```

Comment: killing applications like this may cause a lot of issues - e.g. files may not be written, etc.

Answer (score 0):

'Let's say we're executing a function A() which calls a function B(), can we be sure that the call of B() in A() will always return "after" the call itself'. No, because:

'B' may raise an exception that is not caught in 'A'.

'B' may contain an infinite loop.

'B' may make a blocking OS call that never returns.